# Upload File||The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

**Having problems to store a video to server. I had changed all possible types in mimes.php, but the issue remains same here is my code.**
**Controller**

```
    public function frontsliderAdd()
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in') != TRUE) {
        redirect(base_url() . 'admin/login');
    }
    $data['active'] = 'frontslider';
    if (isset($_POST['addgallery'])) {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Banner Title', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('video_url', 'Video Link', 'trim|required');

        if ($_FILES["video_upload"]['name'] == '') {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('image_upload', 'Image', 'required');
        }

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
            if ($_FILES["video_upload"]['name']) {

                $config['upload_path'] = './public/uploads/banner_images';

                $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg|gif|mp4|avi|mov';

                //$this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $config['max_size'] = '0';
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                if (!$this->upload->do_upload('video_upload')) {
                    $error_msg = $this->upload->display_errors();
                } else {
                    $data['video'] = $this->upload->data();
                }
            }
            $data['title'] = $this->input->post('title');
            $data['video_url'] = $this->input->post('video_url');
            $this->load->model('AdminModel');
            $this->AdminModel->saveGallery($data);
        }
    }
    $data['sidebar'] = $this->load->view('admin/sidebar', NULL, TRUE);
    $this->load->view('admin/header');
    $this->load->view('admin/frontslideradd', $data);
    $this->load->view('admin/footer');
}
```

**Model**

```
    public function saveGallery($data)
{
    $array = array(
        'title' => $data['title'],
        'video' => $data['video']['file_name'],
        'video_url' => $data['video_url']
    );
    $this->db->insert('front_slider', $array);
}
```

**View-add**

```
 <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="image_upload">Upload Video</label>
                                        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="video_upload" name="video_upload">
                                        <span class="help-block" style="color: red;"><?php echo form_error('video_upload') ?></span>
                                    </div>
```

**mimes**

```
'3gp'   =>  array('video/3gp', 'video/3gpp'),
'mp4'   =>  'video/mp4',
```

**It gives no error but successfully passes other data to server except only video Please rectify, thanx in advance**

Comment: Sounds like a server configuration problem. What's your max upload size compared to the size of the video? If the video size exceeds the max you can use, then I would suggest looking into a "chunking" solution.

Comment: As I stated  $config['max_size'] = '0'; sets to unlimited.

Comment: It's never really unlimited unless you yourself control the server and can configure it as such. Do you control the server or is it hosted?

Comment: am i right you question is video file  uploaded But not store in db or you are unable to upload video file  ?

Comment: If it's a hosted server then you can likely find the "max upload size" in their knowledge base, if any. However if it's a server config issue then no amount of programming client side or PHP will resolve your issue without doing a workaround. Hence I mentioned "chunking". Research that keyword.

Comment: @GetSet right now its in simple localhost.

Comment: @BoominathanElango yeah exatly.

Comment: What happens if you upload a file containing just "Hello World"? I ask this because it would be worth knowing if your upload handler in your application even works.

Comment: @getset yeah, I also tried same thing. try to upload gif, .doc. or simple text but it gives null to database..

Comment: Then why in your question you say specifically that video doesn't work? Can you modify your question to "upload doesnt work"? You have to be specific. I just wasted 10 minutes focusing on large file sizes. You will get more help by rewording your problem.

Comment: then how it send pdf to database?

Comment: You may have a db problem. Or the problem could be on the uploading aspect. See @BoominathanElango comment above. You need to see if the file is being uploaded at all as a prerequisite. Then you can save it to db. You have two potential problems, not one.

Comment: @GetSet sorry, there is a miss-information. it can upload gif, pdf, even text files. last time it was not checked, that the text is empty or not. i changed mimes, and its uploaded succesfully, and gif too. thanks btw

Answer (score 0):

> You are storing the upload data in

```
$data['image'] = $this->upload->data();
```

> and assigned wrong key

```
 'video' => $data['video']['file_name'] // Here is your problem
```

> You should change your key as follows

```
'video' => $data['image']['file_name']
```

> Hope this Helps

Comment: It was changed to your proposal  Thank you. But having same problem

Comment: print_r($this->db->last_query); check whats exactly happen

Answer (score 0):

> Stop when error occurs in file upload to get exact error

```
 if (!$this->upload->do_upload('video_upload')) {
             $error_msg = $this->upload->display_errors(); // Make exit here 
             print_r($error_msg);
             exit;
            } else {
                $data['video'] = $this->upload->data(); 
                $data['title'] = $this->input->post('title');
               $data['video_url'] = $this->input->post('video_url');
               $this->load->model('AdminModel');
               $this->AdminModel->saveGallery($data)
            }
```

Comment: thanx, for suggestion. shows
The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.

Comment: @AvikBanerjee change your question title to this `The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed` and mention the video filename extension.

Comment: you should mention the extension of file you are upload in $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg|gif|mp4|avi|mov'; check the extension of file @AvikBanerjee

Comment: @GetSet okay. its .mp4

Comment: @BoominathanElango last comment above is the direction you (Avik Banerjee) should now be headed in. You may need to configure the `$config['allowed_types']`

Comment: @AvikBanerjee even though u only have 9pts reputation you can upvote comments that help you correct?

Comment: @GetSet how to do that?